# Fonts not combining correctly into a family (PC)

Tags: fonts, typography, font-management

I'm using FontCreator 6.5 professional. I have two fonts in the same family, and in "naming" I've given them the same Font Family Name, and in Subfamily one is called Regular and the other is called Italic. But when I drag the two .ttf files to the Fonts folder in windows, only the Italic one is listed, and they aren't combining. But if I delete the Italic version from Fonts, all of the sudden the Regular shows up. I've checked in FontCreator and they each have a Unique Font Identifier.

What can I do to get Windows to see them as two versions of the same font?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody posted a link to an article on font naming, but it was deleted.  [Here's the article](http://www.kltf.de/downloads/FontNaming-kltf.pdf).  It actually does contain useful information for making sure font names are set correctly for display in Windows, though is probably a bit wordy.

The relevant font names for Windows are the TTF Names table.  The "Family" should be the same.  The "Fullname" and "Subfamily" should both be different.  The "Fullname" should usually be a concatenation of the "Family" and the "Subfamily" separated by a space, but if the subfamily is "Regular" or "Normal", it's acceptable to leave off that part in the "Fullname".

I haven't used FontCreator but if it allows you to modify entries in the TTF Names table, that's where you should be looking.

More detailed information on Microsoft about the names table is here:

https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm